# MATLAB - Equivalent logical indexing leading to two different results

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

I'm writing a piece of code for submission through an online grader, as showcased below. B is some given array filled any/all integers 1 through K, and I want to extract the corresponding logical indices of matrix X and perform some operations on those elements, to be put into a return array:

```
for i = 1:K

   A = X(B == i, :);
   returnArr(i, :) = sum(A) / length(A);

end
```

This did not pass the grader at all, and so I looked to change my approach, instead indexing array X indirectly via first using the "find" function, as below:

```
for i = 1:K

    C = find(B == i);
    returnArr(i,:) = sum(X(C,:)) / length(C);

end
```

To my surprise, this code passed the grader without any issues. I know there are a plethora of variations between graders, and one might handle a particular function differently than another, but from a MATLAB functionality/coding perspective, what am I missing in terms of discrepancies between the two approaches? Thanks!

Comment: My first thought is that `length(A)` and `length(C)` may return different results as `A` is a matrix.  What is the size of `A` and `C`?

Comment: Please see [mcve]. You have explanations for `B` and `K`, then pull `X` out of nowhere. Provide a complete example, the results you expect, and the results you actually obtain. The approaches are not equivalent. I would imagine you can explain the differences between the approaches yourself by looking at them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that:

```
length(C) == sum(B == i)
```

while

```
length(A) == max([sum(B == i) , size(X , 2)])
```

In other words, to obtain the same result of the second example with the first one, you should modify it like this:

```
A = X(B == i , :);
returnArr(i, :) = sum(A) / size(A,1);
```

The function [length](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/length.html) returns the *length of largest array dimension*

Comment: I second this answer as it pinpoints the source for the discrepancies. Also, be careful with your usage of `sum` @David. If you do not specify the dimension argument (second), `sum` will behave differently depending on the size of `A`: more than one row -> summation over columns and result will be a 1-by-N vector. one row -> summation over row and result is a scalar. I am not sure what the intended behavior is in your case.